# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "Project.manager" must be a "Profil" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hello I have this error when I start saving a form.

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>": "Project.manager" must be a "Profil" instance.
```

I have two applications account and project

> account.model.py

```
class Profil(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   photo_path = time.strftime('photo/%Y/%m/%d')
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathAndRename(photo_path), blank=True, null=True)
   antity = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ENTITY_TYPE, default=ENTITY_TYPE[0])
   biography = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='Congo-BZV')
   facebook_url = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
   twitter_url = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
   inscrit_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   def __str__(self):
       return "Profil de {0}".format(self.user.username)
```

> project.model.py

```
class Project( models.Model):

   manager = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Profil', related_name='project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


   image_path = time.strftime('images/%Y/%m')
   main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathAndRename(image_path), blank=True)


   slogan = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

   description = RichTextUploadingField(blank = True, null=True)
```

> project.views.py

```
def project_new(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           project = form.save(commit = False)
           project.manager = request.user
           project.save()

   else:
       form = ProjectForm()


   return render(request, 'project/project_new.html', {'form': form})
```

> project.forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

   title = forms.CharField(label='Titre')
   description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
   category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset =  Category.objects.all(), label='Catégorie')

#description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}))


   class Meta:
       model = Project
       fields = ('title', 'nb_days', 'slogan', 'category', 'description')
```

I would like every user or manager to be linked to the project they post via a form.
How could I link the two models by saving a model?

Thank you

Comment: The error seems clear: you are assigning a User instead of a Profil to your Project object. However, the code as you have shown it does not have a manager field in Project; please ensure you show the actual code you are using.

Comment: yes. I mistakenly forgot to add the manager field in project.models.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insted of

```
project.manager = request.user
```

you should use:

```
project.manager = request.user.profil
```